# WordPress removing WWW

Tags: wordpress, url, url-rewriting

I've recently set up a WordPress blog and it's removing the `www` from all URLs. I've disabled all plug-ins, and it still does that.

My `.htaccess` is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I don't see anything wrong with it.

It's the latest version of WordPress.

How can I fix it? I would like to have all URLs with `www`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to adjust this in the UI options / preferences in your running WordPress installation.

Go to "General Settings" and change the "WordPress address (URL)" and "Blog address (URL)" to what is appropriate. In your case, I'd expect that you'd need to add the "www" to it.

Here's a screenshot of the section so it's clear: 
[Screen shot of the general settings area. http://theopensourceu.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/WP-GeneralSettings.JPG](http://theopensourceu.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/WP-GeneralSettings.JPG)

Comment: ^^ Here's "not" the screenshot is what you really mean?

Comment: Post is old, 404: file not found.

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to your .htaccess file.
Wordpress versions since 2.3 will do 301 redirects based on the domain you have set set for your "Blog address(URL)" in Settings → General.